# Как решить проблему с загрузчиком Grub при установке Ubuntu Server 15.04 с USB-флешки?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Решил установить для домашних экспериментов Ubuntu Server 15.04 на нэтбук Toshiba NB520-D10 https://market.yandex.ru/product/6940745?hid=91013&clid=502

1) Выбираю язык. Настраиваю местоположение и клавиатуру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Настраиваю сеть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Указываю зеркало архива и прокси (прокси не заполняю, т.к. его нет)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) Создаю пользователя. Не шифрую домашний каталог. Настраиваю время.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5) Выбираю автоматическую разметку диска (знаю, что это плохой вариант, но сейчас надо просто установить систему).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6) Отказываюсь от автоматического обновления и не устанавливаю пока ни одного пакета.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7) Устанавливаю Grub и получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то может подсказать, как решить данную проблему?

P.S.
Гуглил. Проблема известная. Предлагают много решений. Пока ни одно не подошло.

Дополнительно.

После установки Grub в /dev/sdb1 (встал без ошибок), перезагрузки (разумеется я убрал в BIOS загрузку с флешки) на 2 секунды на черном экране в верхнем левом углу появляется input (мигающая черта приглашения к вводу) и исчезает, остается просто черный экран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Черный экран говорит о том, что нужно открыть какой-либо терминал! 
Нажимаем Alt + F1 и вот оно - приглашение авторизоваться!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант попробуйте после установки загрузиться в live систему:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt #поскольку разбиение стандартное то скорее всего sdb1 система а sdb2 подкачка
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Должно сработать.

Comment: Можно еще попробовать так: grub-install /dev/sdb --boot-directory=/mnt/boot без чрута.

Comment: Что значит "загрузиться в live систему" ? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Machez Вот посмотри на примере [рисунка](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X6dvz.png). Что то типа "попробовать без установки".

Comment: Проблема решилась неожиданно! Смотрите ниже

Comment: Мдааа. Всякое бывает :)